# Where is webconsole.js referenced?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to understand how `webconsole.js` is imported into the Firefox Devtools - It should be imported in toolbar.xul, but I couldn't see were, in either the DOM inspector or Venkman JS debugger.

To be more specific, I'm trying to call `JSTerm.execute(command, callback)` from the inspector.xul context, similar to what happens when you enter somehting in the Web Console. These objects should be in inspector's parent window (the Dev tools main toolbar), but I can't seem to find the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspector and Web Console are two separate tools that normally don't interact. In fact, it's possible for Inspector to be loaded while Web Console isn't. What gets loaded into the browser is `chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul` - that's the toolbar displaying all registered tools (there is a generic API to register tools). When a particular tool is selected, it gets loaded into an `<iframe>` inside `toolbox.xul`, this can be `inspector.xul` or `webconsole.xul`. The latter loads `webconsole.js` then.

In other words, you cannot really use functionality of the web console from the inspector, at least not reliably. The best solution would be copying the parts you need from `webconsole.js` into your code - that way it will work regardless of how developer tools change in future.

Comment: Can you share any info/documentation on this "generic API to register tools"? If I include the `webconsole.js` couldn't it interfere with the inspector.xul I'm overlaying it to?

Comment: Also, why can't I find webconsole.xul in DOM inspector? Is that file only in Beta or Nightly?

Comment: No, it is in the regular Firefox release. Open DOM Inspector, select the Firefox window then click Edit / Select Element By Click - switch back to the Firefox window and click inside the web console output. DOM Inspector now selected an element inside `webconsole.xul`. Loading `webconsole.js` into `inspector.xul` is certainly not something I would recommend, it's very likely to interfere or at least to cause errors - if not now then in a future Firefox version. This is not the environment where it is supposed to run.

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that this iframe doesn't show up in File -> Chrome windows in DOM inspector. I found I could do something to the target element with `selected.node` instead of trying to call the web console with `$0.something`.

Comment: It seems DOM inspector may be taking a snapshot when it was opened, might be why it doesn't show that sometimes.